# How to create nested dictionary from excel sheets and merge them together

Tags: python, json, excel, dictionary, nested-loops

Thank you for your help in advance.  I am new to python. I have the following excel sheets:

```
sheet 1                        sheet 2
A    B    C   D  E             A   B
1    a    27  BG 10            1   url_1
2    b    10  UK 20            1   url_2
3    c    15  US 30            2   url_3
                               4   url_4
```

I would like to create a json data in this format:

```
 {"A": 1,"B":"a","C": "27","D":"BG", "E":"10","webs": [{ "web" :"url_1" , "web" : "url_2" }]},
 {"A": 2,"B": "b","C": "10","D":"UK","E":"20", "webs": [{"web" :"url_3'}]},
 {"A: 3, "B": "c", "C": "15","D":"US", "E":"30", "webs: [{  "web : "url_4" }]}
```

I am having trouble with grouping the second sheet to the first using the following code:

```
for row in range(1, sheet_1.nrows):
    row_values = sheet_1.row_values(row)
    b = {}
    a= row_values[0]
    b['A'] = row_values[0]
    b['B'] = row_values[1]
    b['C'] = row_values[2]
    b['D'] =  row_values[3]
    b['E'] =  row_values[4]

    for rows in range(1, sheet_2.nrows):
        row = sheet_2.row_values(rows)
        if row_values[0] == row[0]:

            b['webs'] = [{'web':row[1]}]

    print(b)
```

Which produce the following output

```
{'A': 1.0, 'B': 'a', 'C': 27.0, 'D': 'BG', 'E': 10.0, 'webs': [{'web': 'url_2'}]}
{'A': 2.0, 'B': 'b', 'C': 10.0, 'D': 'UK', 'E': 20.0, 'webs': [{'web': 'url_3'}]}
{'A': 3.0, 'B': 'c', 'C': 15.0, 'D': 'US', 'E': 30.0, 'webs': [{'web': 'url_4'}]}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b['webs']` variable keeps on updating value instead of storing it in the list and finally stores the value of the last matching row of the second sheet.

```
for row in range(1, sheet_1.nrows):
    row_values = sheet_1.row_values(row)
    b = {}
    b['A'] = row_values[0]
    b['B'] = row_values[1]
    b['C'] = row_values[2]
    b['D'] =  row_values[3]
    b['E'] =  row_values[4]
    temp = [] #Initialize empty list
    for rows in range(1, sheet_2.nrows):
        row = sheet_2.row_values(rows)
        if row_values[0] == row[0]:

            temp.append({'web':row[1]}) #append the item to the list
    b['webs'] = temp
    print(b)
```

This should work for now. But consider exploring Python's Numpy library if you want to work with excel data using Python.